# JPA - many-to-many mapping with join table but missing target table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I'm working with a 3rd party database that has the following 2 tables:

```
Instrument
------
id (pk int not null)
name

InstrumentGroup
------
groupName (pk varchar(25) not null)
instrumentId (pk fk int not null)
```

How can I define an `InstrumentGroup` (or define a `Group`) entity that has a collection of `Instrument`? Note: The database doesn't have a `Group` table`. I currently have:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class InstrumentGroup {
  
  @EmbeddedId
  private InstrumentGroupKey instrumentGroupKey;
}

@Embeddable
@Data
public class InstrumentGroupKey implements Serializable {
   
   private String groupName;
   
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "instrumentId")
   private Instrument instrument;
}
```

Comment: first of all groupname cannot be a PK as it is not unique, second it all dependes on what you want but from this you will have to change the InstrumentGroup table to have at least three fields(IgId(int PK), GroupId(FK), and InstrumentId(FK)

Comment: @Jack M Thanks for your comment. `groupName` is a PK. You're right that it is not unique though. However, `groupName` + `instrumentId` is unique and together forms the composite key.